# Why isn't the filter working?

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I want to filter my product by country and brand, for that reason I have created a view:

```
class CategoryView(ListView):
    template_name = '__index.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'
    paginate_by = 20

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(category__slug=self.kwargs.get('slug')).order_by('-created')

        request = self.request

        # Filter By Brand and Country
        if request.GET.get('country'):
            print(request.GET.get('country'))
            queryset.filter(brand__country__slug=request.GET.get('country'))

        if request.GET.get('brand'):
            print(request.GET.get('brand'))
            queryset.filter(brand__slug=request.GET.get('brand'))

        print(queryset[0].brand.slug)
        print(queryset[0].brand.country.slug)

        return queryset
```

But products isn't filtering when i pass querystring like that: **?brand=astra-gold&country=chehiya** and print function show me:

**chehiya
astra-gold
veneto
italiya**

As you can see chehiya != italiya  and astra-gold != veneto. Bun why this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `filter()` on a queryset, it creates a new queryset. The original queryset is unchanged. For your filter to have an effect, you need to assign the result back to `queryset`, for example:

```
    if request.GET.get('country'):
        print(request.GET.get('country'))
        queryset = queryset.filter(brand__country__slug=request.GET.get('country'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot this

```
queryset = queryset.filter(brand__country__slug=request.GET.get('country'))
```